# Simple normal extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-extension

I was asked to prove that if $a$ is any root of $13x^{4} - 29x^{2} + 13$ then the extension $\mathbb{Q}(a)/\mathbb{Q}$ is a normal extension.

We see that $-a$ is actually another root of the polynomial but I don't know how to show that if $b$ is another root distinct from $a$ and $-a$ then $b\in\mathbb{Q}(a)$.

I know that the polynomial is irreducible since it is a primitive polynomial but doesn't seem to help that is the minimmum polynomial of $a$.
Any hint will be appreciate it.

Comment: The polynomial is $13 (x-a)(x+a)(x-1/a)(x+1/a)$.